# Wikitude определение своей координаты

Tags: javascript

Помогите мне разобраться с проблемой поиска своей координаты, с помощью библиотеки **wikitude**.
Мне нужно расположить модельку на то место, где я стою.

Есть даже функция: `AR.GeoLocation`, в которой и можно задать координату для отрисовки, но я не знаю, как в эту функцию передать свою координату.

Если знаете, как эта проблема решается, помогите, спасибо!